# How to search on the displayed data and not the backing data using Angular

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I am using `ng-repeat` to create a table of data:

```
<div class="divTable" ng-repeat="expense in exp.expenses | filter:exp.query">
    <div>{{expense.amount | ldCurrency : true}}</div>
     ...
</div>
```

A couple of the cells that I am creating are being modified through an `Angular filter`.  In the example above, I am changing the `integer` to a currency.  So the original `4` is changed to `$4.00`.  When I `filter` the entire list with my `exp.query`, it does not modify the `exp.query` search term through the `ldCurrency`.

The means that if I search on `$4`, it will not find it, because the backing data is `4`, even though `$4` is on the page.

I know this is confusing, with the two types of filters that I am talking about here.

How can I search on the data that is being shown on the page and not on the backing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create you own filter. What you want to do to is a bad idea, because you are melding the view layer and the model layer.

A example of a filter.

The html:

```
<input ng-model="query" ng-trim="true">
<span>Finding: </span><span>{{ query }}</span>
<div ng-repeat="product in products | productsFilter: query">
  <strong>{{ $index }}</strong>
  <span>{{ product.name }}</span>
  <span>{{ product.price | currency: '$'}}</span>
</div>
```

The custom filter:

```
.filter('productsFilter', [function () {

  // Private function: It removes the dollar sign.
  var clearQuery = function (dirtyQuery) {

    var index = dirtyQuery.indexOf('$');

    if (index === -1) 
      return dirtyQuery; 

    return dirtyQuery.substr(index+1, dirtyQuery.length-index)
  };

  // The Custom filter
  return function (products, query) {

    if (query === '') return products;

    var newProducts = [];

    angular.forEach(products, function (product) {

      var cleanQuery       = clearQuery(query);
      var strProductPrice  = '' + product.price;
      var index            = strProductPrice.indexOf(cleanQuery);

      if (index !== -1) {
        newProducts.push(product); 
      }
    });

    return newProducts;
  };
}]);
```

The key is in the `angular.forEach`. There I decide if the product will belong to the new filtered collection. Here you can do the match you want.

You can find the complete example in [full plucker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/8xJOefnbWTpXWWRh0oUl/index.html) and see a lot of filters in the [a8m's angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)